# Cannot convert String to double in the middle of a String split class?

Tags: java, string, methods, split

Hi im working on a program for school that reads an input from the user in this form

"String/double/int/int/int" or "String/double/int/int", depending on the shape of the Drink.

Heres the code that I have for the Parser class so far.

```
public class DrinkParser {

    public static Drink parseStringToDrink(String lineToParse){

        String regex = "[/]";
        String [] split = lineToParse.split(regex);

        if ("Box".equals(split[0]) || "box".equals(split[0])){

           DrinkInBox dIB = new DrinkInBox(split[1], split[2], split[3], split[4], split[5]);


        }

        if("Cylinder".equals(split[0]) || "cylinder".equals(split[0])){

            DrinkInCylinder dIC = new DrinkInCylinder(split[1], split[2], split[3], split[4]);

        }

    }



}
```

and heres the code for the DrinkInBox and DrinkInCylinder class...i feel that its relevant.

```
public class DrinkInBox extends Drink {

    private int height;
    private int width;
    private int depth;

    public DrinkInBox(String drinkId, double unitPrice, int height, int width, int depth){

        super(drinkId, unitPrice);
        this.height = height;
        this.width = width;
        this.depth = depth;

    }

    public void computeTotalPrice(){

        volume = height * width * depth;
        totalPrice = volume * unitPrice;

    }

    public String toString(){

        return "\nThe Drink in a Box\nThe Height:\t\t" +height+ "\nThe Width:\t\t" +width+ "\nThe Depth:\t\t" +depth+ "\nThe DrinkId:\t\t" +drinkId+ "\n The Volume:\t\t" +volume+ "\nThe Unit Price:\t\t" +unitPrice+ "\n The Total Price:\t" +totalPrice+ "\n\n";

    }

}
```

heres the DrinkIn Cylinder Class

```
public class DrinkInCylinder extends Drink {

    private int radius;
    private int height;

    public DrinkInCylinder(String drinkId, double unitPrice, int radius, int height){

        super(drinkId, unitPrice);
        this.radius = radius;
        this.height = height;

    }

    public void computeTotalPrice(){

        volume = (int) (Math.PI * (radius*radius) * height);
        totalPrice = volume * unitPrice;

    }

    public String toString(){

        return "\nThe Drink in a Cylinder\nThe Radius:\t\t" +radius+ "\nThe Height:\t\t" +height+ "\nThe DrinkId:\t\t" +drinkId+ "\n The Volume:\t\t" +volume+ "\nThe Unit Price:\t\t" +unitPrice+ "\n The Total Price:\t" +totalPrice+ "\n\n";

    }

}
```

I know its a lot but I appreciate any help that you guys may be able to provide.

Comment: Use method `equalsIgnoreCase()` instead of two `equals()`. Unless your checking exactly for that, which I think you aren't, it'll improve readability and improve performance (by a tiny bit).

Answer (score 2):

```
 DrinkInBox dIB = new DrinkInBox(split[1], split[2], split[3], split[4], split[5]);
```

`split` is a `String[]`, so `split[n]`, `0 <= n <= split.length-1`, will return a `String`. Now lets take a look at your `DrinkInBox` constructor:

```
public DrinkInBox(String drinkId, double unitPrice, int height, int width, int depth)
```

You are passing in 5 `String`s as an arguments but you don't have a `DrinkInBox` constructor that has 5 `String` parameters. You must parse each split accordingly so it matches the parameter types of your `DrinkInBox` constructor.

```
 DrinkInBox dIB = new DrinkInBox(split[1], Double.parseDouble(split[2]), Integer.parseInt(split[3]), Integer.parseInt(split[4]), Integer.parseInt(split[5]));
```

There is also another occurrence of this in your code. You need to do the same thing.

Also, just a tip for improvement, you should be comfortable with inheritance and polymorphism. `DrinkInBox` and `DrinkInCylinder` both have a common super class. You could rewrite as:

```
Drink drink = split[0].equalsIgnoreCase("box") ? new new DrinkInBox(split[1], Double.parseDouble(split[2]), Integer.parseInt(split[3]), Integer.parseInt(split[4]), Integer.parseInt(split[5])) : split[0].equalsIgnoreCase("cylinder") ? new DrinkInCylinder(split[1], Double.parseDouble(split[2]), Integer.parseInt(split[3]), Integer.parseInt(split[4]), Integer.parseInt(split[5])) : null;
```

If it isn't a box or cylinder, `drink` will be `null`. You can check to see if it's a `DrinkInBox` or `DrinkInCylinder` by performing an `instanceof` check:

```
if(drink instanceof DrinkInBox) 
if(drink instanceof DrinkInCylinder)
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. Appreciate the help and I get it now too. Thanks!

Comment: @UsmanHasan If it is helpful, accept it as an answer so more people will actually answer your questions.

Comment: I have no idea as to how to do that...still new to this site. I'd be glad to do it if you'd tell me how.

Comment: @UsmanHasan There should be a check mark on the left hand side of my answer. Press it.